# How can i use keys to clone, read and write to Github on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, github

How can i have my team use Github on Ubuntu to clone, read and write via keys rather then login credentials.

The purpose of this limits them to only work with the code on a development specific server that they do not need Github account credentials, in turn cannot clone on another machine or download as a zip.

Reasons are for code-base security in a remote development environment.

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate ssh key using: ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com" and put them to your key folder. Usually it is ~/.ssh/
2. Give them only read permissions for current user: chmod 400 keyfile
3. Copy public key to Github -> Settings -> Add SSH key
4. Paste your key into the "Key" field.
5. Share private key with colleagues

Comment: Thanks for that - does this allow them to commit to the repo with the read permissions? Each team member has their own ec2 VM in AWS being used  as a remote dev server - where they remote dev using the Atom plugin - Nuclide.

Comment: They need write permission in order to push(write) the code. Here is the list of all repo permissions for organization: https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/

Comment: thanks for that, whats the purpose of changing the permissions on the key file for the current user? then git pull / clone can be done with this key instead of login? Thanks for answering the question.

Comment: key will not be working if someone else except you will have access to it